# Multiple filters with query string

Tags: filter, query-string

Imagine this situation:

- a SharePoint 2010 teamsite
- 2 lists
- 1 query string filter webpart to connected to the first list
- the 1st list is connected to the 2nd to filter the 2nd

When I click an item on the first (filtererd by querystring parameter) list the querystring parameter is gone. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by adding a Choice Filter webpart on the page (hidden) with the same values that you use in the querystring.

The 2nd filter webpart captures the querystring value.